# Union of complement of P and Q is in coNP

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, turing-machines

> Given two problems $P$ and $Q$ are in NP and coNP respectively.
> Defined whether
>
> 1. Union of complement of P and Q is in coNP. (It is true and I have proved this)
> 2. Union of complement of P and Q is in NP.

I wonder whether 2. is true or not. If not, I hope you could give me an example for that.

Comment: It appears that you've written the same thing twice (1. and 2. look the same)! Was that intentional?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Sorry for my typo. I have edited coNP to NP in 2.

Comment: That makes more sense! Now if 2. was true, what happens when you take $P$ to be the trivial problem "accept every input"..?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen You mean that coP = $\varnothing$ and then coP $\cup$ Q = Q?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen But I do not see any contradiction from that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the hint from Izaak, we can choose $P$ to be the trivial problem that accepts every input and $Q$ to be TAUTOLOGY. Now the union you mentioned is exactly $Q$ (now is TAUTOLOGY) which is well-known that is in coNP but not in NP. This make a contradiction.

Comment: Nice answer! It's perhaps worth being a little more explicit in that "$Q$ is not in $\mathrm{NP}$, *assuming that* $\mathrm{NP} \ne \text{co-NP}$." Statement $2$ is in fact equivalent to $\mathrm{NP} = \text{co-NP}$, which gives a sort of "weak negative" answer, since that's an open problem.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yeah, I totally agree with you. By the way, do you know any problem that is in NP but not in coNP?

Comment: Sadly I don't. Nor does anyone else in the world! Since $\mathrm{P} \subseteq \text{co-NP}$, if anyone could prove such a problem exists, they would have proved $\mathrm{P} \ne \mathrm{NP}$. As far as I know, in complexity exercises like this it's therefore acceptable to give answers like "no, assuming that $\mathrm{NP} \ne \text{co-NP}$"